# Maximum independet set of size >= |E|

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, independent-set

Is it NP-hard to find a maximum inpendent set in a graph of size >=|E|. |E| is the number of edges.

My thinking is that it is not possible that there is a independent set of size > |E|. But how hard is it to decide if there is a independet set of size exactly |E|?

Comment: Degenerate example: a lone vertex: independent set 1, |E|=0. As for NP completeness, you can start your research in the related wikipedia article.